# Durandal Google Maps not showing properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js, durandal

Trying to show Google Maps using the Durandal. I'm now simply working with [Durandal HTML Starter Kit](http://durandaljs.com/get-started.html) so the other modules and all engine works properly. The thing is when I added the Google Map it doesn't fit the div size (the big part of div is just grey). As I understand, the problem is causing because Google Maps added before page is completely loaded. But I can't figure out how can I hook on page load event. Here is the module code:

```
define(['knockout', 'gmaps'], function (ko, gmaps) {

    return {
        displayName: 'Google Maps',
        myMap: ko.observable({
            lat: ko.observable(32),
            lng: ko.observable(10)}),

        activate: function () {
            console.log('activate');
            ko.bindingHandlers.map = {

                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    console.log('init');
                    var mapObj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

                    var latLng = new gmaps.LatLng(
                        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lat),
                        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lng));

                    var mapOptions = { center: latLng,
                        zoom: 5,
                        mapTypeId: gmaps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

                    mapObj.googleMap = new gmaps.Map(element, mapOptions);
                }
            }
        },

        attached: function() {
            console.log('attached');

        },

        compositionComplete: function()
        {
            console.log('compositionComplete');


        }

    };


});
```

And a very simple HTML code:

```
<section>
    <div id="gmap-canvas" data-bind="map:myMap"></div>
</section>
```

I'm loading Google Maps with async plug-in in my shell.js. It works fine.
Screenshot with trouble here - **Offending link removed**

P.S. div size is defined in .CSS file.

P.S. I tried to use getElementById approach provided [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=en) and it's work great if placed in **compositionComplete** block. But when I tried to move my bindings to this block nothing happens at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I will not argue that the problem was in my small experience in durandal but the solution is following:
Use `composition.addBindingHandler` to make delayed bindings. I want to clarify - method with map resizing was not working for me. Here is the my gmap.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'gmaps', 'durandal/composition'], function (ko, gmaps, composition) {
    composition.addBindingHandler('googleMap', {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var mapObj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            var latLng = new gmaps.LatLng(37.774107,-122.420853);
            //  ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lat),
            //  ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lng));

            var mapOptions = {
                center:latLng,
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: gmaps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

            mapObj.googleMap = new gmaps.Map(element, mapOptions);

        }
    });

    return {
        displayName: 'Map',
        map:ko.observable({}),
        activate: function()
        {
            console.log('activate');
        }
    }

});
```

Here is my gmap.html:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html: displayName"></h2>
    <div id="gmap-canvas" data-bind="googleMap:map"></div>
</section>
```

Here is how I loaded the Google Maps in the main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text':          '../lib/require/text',
        'async':         '../lib/require/plugins/async',
        'propertyParser':'../lib/require/plugins/propertyParser',
        'goog':         '../lib/require/plugins/goog',
        'durandal':      '../lib/durandal/js',
        'plugins' :      '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
        'transitions' :  '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
        'bootstrap':     '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        'knockout':      '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0'
    }
});

define('jquery', ['../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'], function() { return jQuery; });

define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'],
    function(){
        console.log('Google maps loaded');
        return window.google.maps;
    });

define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator'],  function (system, app, viewLocator) {
    //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");
...
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We use Google Maps and it works just fine.

Do the following:

- Move your binding to a bindings.js file, and place the bindings in an `init()` function, making sure to return `init` in an object literal; bindings.js simply contains a singleton module, which we call "bindings" (you can call it whatever you want)
- Make sure you have `async`, `propertyParser`, and `goog` in your require paths
- In main.js, call `bindings.init()` to initialize your bindings

Concerning `async`, `propertyParser`, and `goog`, they should look similar to this:

```
requirejs.config({
     paths: {        
        'async': '../Scripts/plugins/async',
        'propertyParser': '../Scripts/plugins/propertyParser',
        'goog': '../Scripts/plugins/goog',
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** The three plugins--`async`, `propertyParser`, and `goog`--can be found [here](https://github.com/radicand/requirejs-plugins).

Before the function that kicks of your app in main.js, you should also have this, more or less right after the paths are configured (as shown above):

```
define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'],
function () {
    // return the gmaps namespace for brevity
    return window.google.maps;
});
```

That should set you up to go.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:** Whatever you do with a map, you shouldn't do it until at least the `attached` handler in a Durandal viewModel.

**[EDIT] Response to Code Review**

Let's work through this bit by bit:

1. Reverse the order of your `propertyParser` and `goog` *paths* definition on the RequireJS `config` object;
2. Remove knockout from your *paths* definition and place it before your `gmaps` define in main.js and do the same for jQuery
3. Remove "v=3&" from your `gmaps` define;
4. I'm suspicious of your observable definition of `myMap` on your viewModel.  I don't see why `myMap` itself needs to be observable.  But I *do* see the point, obviously, of its two properties' being observable.  Remove the outer observable on `myMap`;

On #2 above, you should have in main.js just before your `gmaps` define the following:

```
define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
```

I think this is where you're smashing into the Durandal framework.

Comment: Can't find anything about propertyParser and goog. Google give me nothing. Where I can find this libs and what they do? Another question is - is it okay to keep all bindings in one file? With grow of project this file be extremely big.. I think..

Comment: @user1891037 Sorry about that.  I just edited my answer to include a "NOTE" that references where you can get these plugins. And, yes, it's O.K. to keep all of the custom bindings in one file.  We do.  I imagine if they grow to too many in number, we might need to break them apart for management and maintenance purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Here is an another question: Can I make KO mapping in "compositionComplete:" block? "init:" function in compositionComplete doesn't triggers. However, it triggers if the same code is placed in "activate:" block.

Comment: @user1891037 I'm sure I know what you're saying.  Do you mean KO _binding_? Or are you referring to the KO mapping plugin?  It sounds like you might need to ask a separate question and post some code.  Also, if the answer above I gave is acceptable to you, you might want to "accept" it so others know that it is an appropriate answer.

Comment: Can't make it works with your approach. All the binding now moved to the binding.js file. I also made a 'require' of 'gmaps' module in binding.js to make sure, that bindings will made after gmaps loaded as following: define('bindings', ['knockout', 'gmaps'], function (ko, gmaps).  And i added init function call to my main start function - define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'bindings'],  function (system, app, viewLocator, bindings) {
    bindings.init(); . Results is the same.. Where should I hook on the "attached" event? In which model?

Comment: @user1891037 Please post your code because we have it working just fine here.  I will need to see your main.js, your shell.js (if applicable), your view, and your viewModel (where you're trying to instantiate your gmap).  Also, please provide version numbers of all constituent parts. Thanks.

Comment: I just uploaded the whole project to my dropbox as .zip archive. Here is the link - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33613618/DurandalAdvanced.zip .Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user1891037 Please read the edit at the end of my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the div that the map was bound to was hidden upon the viewmodel activation.  A quick fix was to resize the map via an api call:

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1

You can do this call in a KO custom binding so that it calls the api on update when the div is visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried to resize the map. It gives me nothing. I even tried to resize the map in every compose state - activate, attached, compositionComplete - nothing..

Comment: Did you do the resize in the ko.bindingHandlers update method?  The map needs to be visible on the DOM to resize.  It's worked for me.  If it doesn't work, I can try and set it up on a JSFiddle for you.

Comment: I call the resize in 'compositionComplete' method (or in any other, like activate, attached). All the ko bindings I tried to make in 'activate' method.

Comment: I double-checked my implementation.  What I had done was add a resize ko binding on the div outside of the map div tied to an observable that would be true when the map js calls were done.  That resize div would then call the map api to resize - which would result in the inner map being resized.  Basically something like this.  This was the map being ready can trigger the resize.  The map being ready can be set when the mapping results are received.  Hope this is clearer.

<div data-bind="resizeMap:{}">
<!-- ko if: mapReady() -->
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element.getAttribute('id')), mapOptions);

         function googleMap() {
         google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
         map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(value.centerLat, value.centerLon));
  }
```

Then you can call `googleMap`

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix here is to wait until the page is fully loaded and then initiate the Google Map div or whatever.  To test this quickly simply move all the logic that initializes the map into your compositionComplete callback -

```
compositionComplete: function()
{
    // Initialize your stuff here
}
```

And if (when) that serves your purpose take a good hard look at what your binding handler is doing and decide where that should actually go.  I don't think it should be registered where it currently is because bindingHandlers are available globally via `ko.` once they are registered.  You don't want to re-register it each time once your ViewModel is instantiated.

Comment: Yeap, I already wrote in my question this: "P.S. I tried to use getElementById approach provided here and it's work great if placed in compositionComplete block. But when I tried to move my bindings to this block nothing happens at all."